# Adding Column with CASE in sub-select

Tags: mysql

I have a sub-select within a larger query and I'm trying to add a calculated field to the sub-select using a CASE statement.

My sub-select looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT Course_ID, Question_ID, Answer, (HIP =
        CASE
            WHEN Question_ID = 77 THEN "1"
            WHEN Question_ID = 78 THEN "2"
            WHEN Question_ID = 79 THEN "3"
            WHEN Question_ID = 80 THEN "4"
            WHEN Question_ID = 81 THEN "5"
            WHEN Question_ID = 82 THEN "6"
            ELSE "Undefined HIP"
        END)
    FROM proposals.new_gen_ed_answers
    WHERE Answer = 1
) ercehip
    ON course.Course_ID = ercehip.Course_ID
```

When I try to access ercehip.HIP in my parent select statement though, it says it is undefined. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Can  you access other columns? ercehip.CourseId for example

Comment: This doesn't even syntax.

Comment: @Pelin Yes, the other fields were accessible and the join was correct, but the alias syntax was wrong. However, it did execute past that point which seems interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of using `HIP = (..)`, you will need to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) instead.
- Also, since all your [`CASE .. WHEN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) are checking against `Question_ID` only, you can move it to besides `Case` clause, and make the query less verbose.

Try the following instead:

```
(
    SELECT Course_ID, Question_ID, Answer, 
        (CASE Question_ID
            WHEN 77 THEN "1"
            WHEN 78 THEN "2"
            WHEN 79 THEN "3"
            WHEN 80 THEN "4"
            WHEN 81 THEN "5"
            WHEN 82 THEN "6"
            ELSE "Undefined HIP"
        END) AS HIP 
    FROM proposals.new_gen_ed_answers
    WHERE Answer = 1
) AS ercehip
```

Answer (score 1):

You must determinate alias of the calculated field as MySQL syntax require

```
SELECT Course_ID, Question_ID, Answer, (
    CASE
        WHEN Question_ID = 77 THEN "1"
        WHEN Question_ID = 78 THEN "2"
        WHEN Question_ID = 79 THEN "3"
        WHEN Question_ID = 80 THEN "4"
        WHEN Question_ID = 81 THEN "5"
        WHEN Question_ID = 82 THEN "6"
        ELSE "Undefined HIP"
    END) as HIP
FROM proposals.new_gen_ed_answers
WHERE Answer = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT Course_ID, Question_ID, Answer, (
    CASE
        WHEN Question_ID = 77 THEN "1"
        WHEN Question_ID = 78 THEN "2"
        WHEN Question_ID = 79 THEN "3"
        WHEN Question_ID = 80 THEN "4"
        WHEN Question_ID = 81 THEN "5"
        WHEN Question_ID = 82 THEN "6"
        ELSE "Undefined HIP"
    END) HIP
FROM proposals.new_gen_ed_answers
WHERE Answer = 1
```